# Workflow Failed on Start (retrying)

Tags: 2010, error, designer-workflow

I built a workflow with sharepoint designer to update an item in list A when an item is changed in list B. The workflow starts when the item is changed. Sometimes i get an error message: "Failed on Start (retrying)". I search in the worklfow history and found this message: "System.Workflow.ComponentModel.WorkflowTerminatedException"
If i stop the workflow with this status (Failed...) and start it manually it works fine. 
Why i get the failed status? And why i just get sometimes this error?

Comment: You should look into the ULS logs to see if there are more details about the exception

Comment: Are you using workflow 2013?

Comment: I'm working with workflow 2010. And the logs show something that i never heard before: "recursive workflow are not permitted". I seems like more complicated as i expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess u are triggering workflow for same list item. Like, you are starting workflow when item changed and you are trying to change same list item with workflow again. So it returns that error.

Comment: Yes that's it!! Now i'm working with one workflow and the error is gone.

Comment: Can you please explain what you did to solve this a little further? I'm having the same problem. List A updates item in List B-- that update kicks off WF in list B. I had  it working at one time now I get the same error, "Workflow Failed on Start"